# Spring boot using wrong message convertor

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2

I have a rest endpoint like below which is supposed to accept an XML input, do some processing on it and then return a response in XML as well.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/v1/test/listener", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponseType> processBooking(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) throws JAXBException {
    MyResponseType response = myService.process(myRequest);
    // ... do something with it and generate 'response' 
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And `MyRequest` class looks like below which is autogenerated via jaxb and an external xsd which I cannot change (details omitted from the class)

```
/**
 * MyRequest
 */
public class MyRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    protected SomeEnum someEnum;

    ...

    @XmlType(name = "SomeEnum")
    @XmlEnum
    public enum SomeEnum {

        ACTIVITY,
        DEPOSIT,
        EQUIPMENT,
        FEE,
        MISC,
        PROTECTION,
        RENTAL,
        TAX,
        DISCOUNT;

        public static SomeEnum fromValue(String v) {
            return valueOf(v);
        }

        public String value() {
            return name();
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I try to run it, I get the following error message

> 2018-04-09 11:47:59.378  WARN 2702 --- [           main]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP
>   message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of MyRequest.SomeEnum: no
>   String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String
>   value ('MISC'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of MyRequest.SomeEnum: no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from String value ('MISC')

A sample xml that I send as input is

```
<myRequest>
    ...
    <advertiserAssignedId>19ABC12331</advertiserAssignedId>
    <listingExternalId>ABC123</listingExternalId>
    <unitExternalId>ABC123</unitExternalId>
    <someEnum>
        <name>MISC</name>
        <feeType>MISC</feeType>
        ...
    </someEnum>

    ... 
</myRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what is your endpoint consuming using the [consumes attribut](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--) .

When you post the request to your endpoint, don't forget to set the `Content-type` header to `application/xml`